# how to validate year of completion < current year means (year of completion < 2014) by using jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

how to validate year of completion < current year means (year of completion < 2014)

by using jquery

```
   <tr><td><label><span><font color="red">*</font></span>Year Of Completion</label>
       </td><td><span><select class="textbox4" name="UGYearOfCompletion" id="UGYearOfCompletion">                                  
       <option selected="selected" value="">-select-</option>   <option value="2017">2017</option>   <option value="2016" >2016</option>   <option value="2015" >2015</option>   <option value="2014" >2014</option>   <option value="2013" >2013</option>   <option value="2012" >2012</option>   <option value="2011" >2011</option>   <option value="2010">2010</option>   <option value="2009" >2009</option>   <option value="2008" >2008</option>   <option value="2007" >2007</option>   <option value="2006" >2006</option>   <option value="2005" >2005</option>   <option value="2004" >2004</option>   <option value="2003" >2003</option>   <option value="2002" >2002</option>   <option value="2001" >2001</option>   <option value="2000" >2000</option>   <option value="1999" >1999</option>   <option value="1998" >1998</option>   <option value="1997" >1997</option>   <option value="1996" >1996</option>   <option value="1995" >1995</option>   <option value="1994" >1994</option>   <option value="1993" >1993</option>   <option value="1992" >1992</option>   <option value="1991" >1991</option>   <option value="1990" >1990</option>   <option value="1989" >1989</option>   <option value="1988" >1988</option>   <option value="1987" >1987</option>   <option value="1986" >1986</option>   <option value="1985" >1985</option>   <option value="1984" >1984</option>   <option value="1983" >1983</option>   <option value="1982" >1982</option>   <option value="1981" >1981</option>   <option value="1980" >1980</option>   <option value="1979" >1979</option>   <option value="1978" >1978</option>   <option value="1977" >1977</option>   <option value="1976" >1976</option>   <option value="1975" >1975</option>   <option value="1974" >1974</option>   <option value="1973" >1973</option>   <option value="1972" >1972</option>   <option value="1971" >1971</option>   <option value="1970" >1970</option>   <option value="1969" >1969</option>   <option value="1968" >1968</option>   <option value="1967" >1967</option>   <option value="1966" >1966</option>   <option value="1965" >1965</option>   <option value="1964" >1964</option>   <option value="1963" >1963</option>   <option value="1962" >1962</option>   <option value="1961" >1961</option>   <option value="1960" >1960</option>   <option value="1959" >1959</option>   <option value="1958" >1958</option>   <option value="1957" >1957</option>   <option value="1956" >1956</option>   <option value="1955" >1955</option>   <option value="1954" >1954</option>   <option value="1953" >1953</option>   <option value="1952" >1952</option>   <option value="1951" >1951</option>   <option value="1950" >1950</option>                     
       </select></span></td>
```

Comment: Where is your jquery?

Comment: jQuery.validator.addMethod("yearCount", function(value, element) {
   var x = ($('#UGYearOfCompletion')),
   d = new Date();
   curr_year = d.getFullYear();
   y = ($('#UGYearOfCompletion').val() <= curr_year),
   z = y;
   return z;
}, "Invalid Year");

Comment: now its working...,thankyou for responding